# Weighted homogeneous polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

Why the polynomial $f(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4):=z_1z_4+z_2^3+z_3^3+z_4^5$ is a weighted homogeneous polynomial with weights $\left(\frac54 ,3,3,5\right)$?
(Recall that a polynomial $f=f(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ is called weighted homogeneous with weights $(w_1, \ldots , w_n)$ if it can be expressed as a linear combination of monomials $z_1^{i_1} \cdots z_n^{i_n}$ such that $\frac{i_1}{w_1}+ \cdots + \frac{i_n}{w_n}=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Say $z_i$ has weight $w_i$ for $1 \le i \le 4$. Then for the monomials in $f$ we have
$$z_1z_4 \to \frac1{w_1}+\frac1{w_4}, \quad z_2^3 \to \frac3{w_2}, \quad z_3^3 \to \frac{3}{w_3}, \quad z_4^5\to \frac5{w_4}$$
If we want all of them to be $1$, we need $$(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4) = \left(\frac54 ,3,3,5\right).$$